# Rails3 Engine -- Controller scoped inside engine module returning load error by client app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

I just created my first engine. It adds a couple of new routes like so:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope :module => 'contact' do
    get "contact", :to => 'contacts#new'
    get "contact/send_email", :to => 'contacts#send_email', :as => 'send_email'
  end
end
```

Then, in /websites/Engines/contact/app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb, I have:

```
module Contact
  class ContactsController < ApplicationController

    # Unloadable marks your class for reloading between requests
    unloadable

    def new
      @contact_form = Contact::Form.new
    end

    def send_email
      @contact_form = Contact::Form.new(params[:contact_form])

      if @contact_form.valid?
        Notifications.contact(@contact_form).deliver
        redirect_to :back, :notice => 'Thank you! Your email has been sent.'
      else
        render :new
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I loaded it up in the client app's console to prove to myself some basics were working and quickly got this load error (which I then confirmed by reproducing the issue in a browser):

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > Contact::Form.new
 => #<Contact::Form:0x2195b70> 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > app.contact_path
 => "/contact" 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > r = Rails.application.routes; r.recognize_path(app.contact_path)
LoadError: Expected /websites/Engines/contact/app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb to define ContactsController
```

And there you have it; /contact gets to the engine's contacts_controller.rb but the fact the controller is inside the module Contact makes it unrecognizable.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ryan-bigg and @nathanvda  their answers in conjunction fixed this issue for me. In short, I ended up using the following routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope :module => 'contact' do
    get  "contact", :to => 'contacts#new'
    post "contact/send_email", :to => 'contacts#send_email', :as => 'send_email'
  end
end
```

with the following controller:

```
module Contact
  class ContactsController < ApplicationController

    def new
      @contact_form = Contact::Form.new
    end

    def send_email
      @contact_form = Contact::Form.new(params[:contact_form])

      if @contact_form.valid?
        Contact::Mailer.contact_us(@contact_form).deliver
        redirect_to :back, :notice => 'Thank you! Your email has been sent.'
      else
        render :new
      end
    end

  end
end
```

but what seemed to be the final piece was @nathanvda's suggestions to move the contacts_controller from:

```
/app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb
```

to

```
/app/controllers/contact/contacts_controller.rb
```

Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Your `app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb` is actually defining the `Contact::ContactsController`, not the `ContactsController` that Rails expects.

The problem is with your routes,  they should be defined like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope :module => 'contact' do
    get "contact", :to => 'contact/contacts#new'
    get "contact/send_email", :to => 'contact/contacts#send_email', :as => 'send_email'
  end
end
```

Comment: Right. I want my engine's ContactsController scoped inside the Contact module so there is no chance for collision unless you know exactly what you are doing. So I guess my question should be how do I get rails to expect Contact::ContactsController rather than just ContactsController? I thought that is what I was doing by placing my contact routes inside scope :module => 'contact'

Comment: Also note you should place the controller in the correct folder: `app/controllers/contact/contacts_controller.rb`